# Changing the selection color in the flexviewer 2.4?

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, arcgis-flex-viewer

I am under the impression that by changing the 4th color (in this case 0x000000) will change the Selection color.  However, when I go use the search tool, my results are still displayed in the old color.  You used to be able to set the color in the Identify tool.

```
<style>
<colors>0xFFFFFF,0x333333,0x101010,0x000000,0xFFD700</colors>
<alpha>0.8</alpha>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to modify the SearchWidget.mxml in FlashBuilder, and the recompile the widget.

this is where in the code you would change the colors

```
  //line symbol
                const resultLineSymbolColor:uint = configXML.symbols.simplelinesymbol.@color || 0x33FFFF;
                const resultLineSymbolAlpha:Number = (configXML.symbols.simplelinesymbol.@alpha[0] != null) ? configXML.symbols.simplelinesymbol.@alpha : 0.8;
                const resultLineSymbolWidth:Number = (configXML.symbols.simplelinesymbol.@width[0] != null) ? configXML.symbols.simplelinesymbol.@width : 2;
                resultLineSymbol = new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, resultLineSymbolColor, resultLineSymbolAlpha, resultLineSymbolWidth);

                // fill symbol
                const resultFillSymbolColor:uint = configXML.symbols.simplefillsymbol.@color || 0x33FFFF;
                const resultFillSymbolAlpha:Number = (configXML.symbols.simplefillsymbol.@alpha[0] != 0x33FFFF) ? configXML.symbols.simplefillsymbol.@alpha : 0.5;
                const resultFillSymbolOutlineColor:uint = configXML.symbols.simplefillsymbol.outline.@color || 0x33FFFF;
                const resultFillSymbolOutlineAlpha:Number = (configXML.symbols.simplefillsymbol.outline.@alpha[0] != null) ? configXML.symbols.simplefillsymbol.outline.@alpha : 0.8;
                const resultFillSymbolOutlineWidth:Number = (configXML.symbols.simplefillsymbol.outline.@width[0] != null) ? configXML.symbols.simplefillsymbol.outline.@width : 2;
                resultFillSymbol = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, resultFillSymbolColor, resultFillSymbolAlpha, new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID, resultFillSymbolOutlineColor, resultFillSymbolOutlineAlpha, resultFillSymbolOutlineWidth));
```